# SQL Substituting an expression in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to substitute a variable with an expression in SQL Server.

For example:

```
Declare @someString varchar(50)
set @someString = 's.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal'
Select @someString * 29,@someString + 33,@someString /2 from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as s
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to multiply/add/divide your string with those integers or just want to concat them? If you want to do math operations then change your string datatype to integer...

Comment: Do you want this for less typing (reuse code) or are you going to have different formulas in the expression and use the expression as a parameter to the query? Where does `@someString` come from? Who makes it up?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you should enclose your `@someString` in brackets or you're going to get some fairly interesting results.

Comment: Why do you actually want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to create a store procedure for reporting, instead of having lengthy combinations ('s.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal') in my select statement , i am looking for an alternative. so i came up with an idea of having my combination in a variable and use it for adding division etc..Is there any better way –

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Declare @someString varchar(50)
DECLARE @query varchar(1000)

set @someString = 's.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal'
set @query = 'Select (' + @someString + ') * 29,(' + @someString + ') 
             + 33,(' + @someString + ')/2 from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as s'

EXEC(@query)
```

But you do need to be careful what you are concatenating together, to avoid problems with SQL injection.

Comment: +1 : Although directing someone to `sp_executesql` allows parameterised queries and best practice coding behaviour.  *(Not necessary here, just that it's better in th elong run to start as you mean to go on.)*

Comment: I am trying to create a store procedure for reporting, instead of having lengthy combinations ('s.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal') in my select statement , i am looking for an alternative. so i came up with an idea of having my combination in a variable and use it for adding division etc..Is there any better way

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(50)
SET @someString = 's.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SomeString + ' * 29, ' + 
                        @SomeString + ' + 33, ' + 
                        @SomeString + ' / 2 
            FROM    Sales.SalesorderDetail AS s'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: +1 : Although directing someone to `sp_executesql` allows parameterised queries and best practice coding behaviour.  *(Not necessary here, just that it's better in th elong run to start as you mean to go on.)*

Answer (score 1):

From a comment

> instead of having lengthy combinations (...) in my select statement

You can use `cross apply` to do the calculation and reuse the calculated value in your calculations.

```
select c.Value * 29,
       c.Value + 33,
       c.Value / 2
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as s
  cross apply (select s.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount + s.LineTotal) as c(Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @someString integer
set @someString = 's.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal'
Select @someString * 29,@someString + 33,@someString /2 from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as s
```

OR

```
Declare @someString varchar(50)
set @someString = 's.UnitPrice + s.UnitPriceDiscount+s.LineTotal'
Select (@someString+'* 29') AS Col1,(@someString+'+ 33') AS Col2,(@someString+'/2') AS Col3 from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as s
```

Comment: Option 1 is assigning a string to a an INT.  That's no even possible.